# IIS Output Caching - Can I cache POST requests?

Tags: iis

I'm attempting to cache a ridiculously convoluted API that effectively has GET requests as POSTs.
I'm trying to use Output Caching to achieve this as I hoped it might do the job
but I'm currently stuck in a FREB log:

```
RenderingInfo Culture="en-GB">
  <Opcode>HTTPSYS_CACHEABLE</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>Cache</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Reason">VERB_NOT_GET</freb:Description>
  <freb:Description Data="CachePolicy">NO_CACHE</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
```

Where its just basically saying no cause its a POST.
Am I stuffed? Am I going to have to write this layer myself or do I have options?

Answer (score 1):

I have assumed I cannot and have switched to using an nginX layer for caching. Its awesome because it lets me cache POSTs and define the key for each one (url+body+one-specific-header is what I need).